# Is it possible to restrict access to a System Service in AOSP?

Tags: java, android, proxy, android-source, system-services

Is it possible to restrict access to certain methods on a System Service in AOSP?

I was thinking of having two Proxies talk to the System Service with one implementing public methods and the other just methods to privileged processes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to restrict access to particular methods in system service in AOSP. To enforce IPC permissions Android typically uses AndroidManifest declared permissions.

You can use `AlarmManagerService#setTime(long)` as an example:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/apex/jobscheduler/service/java/com/android/server/alarm/AlarmManagerService.java;l=2980?q=alarmmanagerservice

```
    public boolean setTime(long millis) {
        getContext().enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(
                "android.permission.SET_TIME",
                "setTime");

        return setTimeImpl(millis);
    }
```

The permission itself is defined in an xml file in frameworks:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml;l=3338

```
<!-- Allows applications to set the system time directly.
     <p>Not for use by third-party applications. -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged|role" />
```

Note that based on the protectionLevel used it is not possible for regular Android apps to obtain this permission. The `enforceCallingOrSelfPermission` allows processes with system UID access as well if you follow the implementation to the `ActivityManager#checkComponentPermission(...)` method. I'm not entirely clear on the "role" permission, that appears to be a fairly recent addition to AOSP.